# Cannot handle state of checkbox upon page reload in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, local-storage, use-effect

I'm trying to make a todo list app by using React and Material UI. Everything works fine except checkbox state. I'm saving each todo as object in todo list array in local storage as below.

- todoList is the state that I store each todo.
- isCompleted also a state with default boolean value of false

```
 let arr = todoList;
 const newTodo = new TodoItem({
                id: randomID,
                text: text,
                date: date,
                status: isCompleted
            });

 setTodoList([newTodo, ...arr]);
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoList));
```

In another component I get saved items from local storage by useEffect and render them as todo list. I'm trying to get stored items every time ***isCompleted*** changes.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let savedItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
        if (savedItem !== null) {
            setTodoList(savedItem);
        }
    }, [isCompleted])
```

- This is the checkbox that should change read status.

```
  <FormControlLabel
       control={
       <Checkbox
       onChange={(e) => changeStatus(e.target.checked,index)}
       color="primary"
        />
       }
  />
```

- This is the function supposed to change status. Click handler works fine, it changes status with each click. However, the problem is when I refresh the page, checkbox resets itself to empty state even though status of todo completed in local storage.

```
 const changeStatus = (val,num) => {

        let item = todoList[num];
        if(val === false){
            setIsCompleted(true);
            item.status = isCompleted;

        }else if(val === true){
            setIsCompleted(false);
            item.status = isCompleted;
        }
        
        let storedItems = [...todoList];
        itemsToRender = storedItems;
        storedItems = storedItems.map(todo => todo.id === item.id ? todo = item : todo)
        console.log('STORED',storedItems);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedItems));
    }
```

- note that I'm mapping itemsToRender array to display todos in the component.

How can I prevent checkbox to reset itself(unchecked), I need checkbox to stay checked after reloading the page.

To me, I'm doing something wrong with useEffect or MUI checkbox component.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the checkbox a controlled input by specifying the value attribute on it. And set the value attribute equal to the `todo.status`

```
todoList.map(todo => 
    (<FormControlLabel
        control={
            <Checkbox
               onChange={(e) => changeStatus(e.target.checked,index)}
               color="primary"
               value={todo.status}
            />
        }
    />)
)
```